# i have a WITH clause wont behave as intended

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I found this WITH clause that I modified to my purpose. I can't say that I fully understand how it works when I referee to it within it self?

As you can see from the picture i get duplicates on the last lines "4 gjutning" and "5 Målning".

[image]

So basically have a relation table for different panels where you should be able to set a work flow. One panel follows another,  in this case i also have parallel panels. "3 Montering A" and "3 Montering B" are paralel panels which can be seen from the RunOrder, they are then merging in to "4 Gjutning" followed by "5 Målning"

```
WITH PanelStructure as
(
  Select  p.factoryId, p.name Panel, p.HasScreen, ppr.ParentPanelId, ppr.PanelId, CAST(ppr.PanelId AS VarChar(Max)) as Level, CAST(1 AS int) RunOrder from PanelProductRelation ppr
inner JOIN  Panel p on ppr.PanelId=p.id
where ppr.productid=1 and ParentPanelId=0 and p.CustomerId=7 --and p.HasScreen=1
  UNION ALL
  Select  p2.factoryId, p2.name Panel,p2.HasScreen, ppr2.ParentPanelId, ppr2.PanelId,CAST(ppr2.PanelId AS VarChar(Max)) + ', ' + M.Level, CAST(1 AS int) + M.RunOrder
    from PanelProductRelation ppr2
    Inner JOIN  Panel p2 on ppr2.PanelId=p2.id
     INNER JOIN PanelStructure M ON m.PanelId = ppr2.ParentPanelId
    where ppr2.productid=1 and p2.CustomerId=7 and p2.HasScreen=1
 )
SELECT ps.* From PanelStructure  ps
LEFT JOIN (Select ps2.ParentPanelId ParentPanelId ,count(ParentPanelId) ParentPanelIdCount from PanelStructure ps2 group by ps2.ParentPanelId  ) dup ON dup.ParentPanelId=ps.ParentPanelId
;
```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand why i cant insert an image? Just acts as a link when uploaded. How can i include the result as text?

Comment: For a newbe, can you give som advise how i the best way can share database information such as tables and content? Thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Understand why pictures arnt that great, now it was merly the result i tried to visualize, but to be better on the code, how can i format it to be readable, like tables etc? Ttrying to use this SQL doodle so see if i can share an example there

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever thought about including `distinct` to your `select` statement? So no double rows will be in your Result.